# How should I set default values in CKEditor5?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I am registering and editing through CKEditor in React.

In order to edit a post, I need to output the data received from the DB to ckEditor as it is. How can I make the value remain in the editor? ckEditor keeps showing a blank screen.

I need help, Thanks.

- Below is part of my code.

```
 <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        onChange={handleCkeditorState}
         config={
        {
            fontSize:{
                options: [
                    9, 11, 13, 21, 'default', 38, 48
                ]
              },
            toolbar: {
                items : [ 
                    'heading',
          '|',
          'fontSize',
          'fontFamily',
          'fontColor',
          'fontBackgroundColor',
          'imageInsert',
          '|',
          'bold',
          'italic',
          'underline',
          'strikethrough',
          'highlight',
          'removeFormat',
          '|',
          'alignment',
          '|',
          'numberedList',
          'bulletedList',
          '|',
          'indent',
          'outdent',
          '|',
          'todoList',
          'link',
          'blockQuote',
          'imageUpload',
          'insertTable',
          'mediaEmbed',
          '|',
          'undo',
          'redo',
          'CKFinder'
                 ]
            }
              
        }
       } 
      />
```

```
I've tried things like below with properties.
defaultValue, value, initailValue...
```